# Is there a SequenceMatcher in R?

Tags: r

I found Python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) really useful and I was wondering if there is something similar to `SequenceMatcher` in R.

Here, there is a Python example of what I would like to get in R:

```
>>> s = SequenceMatcher(None, "abcd", "bcde")
>>> s.ratio()
0.75
>>> s.quick_ratio()
0.75
>>> s.real_quick_ratio()
1.0
```

Comment: Hi, You may find pmatch(https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pmatch.html) interesting. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure of the functionality you're looking, but after splitting your characters -`x = strsplit("abcd", NULL)[[1]]; y = strsplit("bcde", NULL)[[1]]`- you could use `2 * sum(x %in% y) / (length(x) + length(y))`

Comment: `stringdist` has various functionalities like cosine/jaccard distance between strings. But I am not sure it has anything for exact sequences.

Comment: @alexis_laz This works fine in some cases but, if we compare "1234" and "4321", your code returns 1 and SequenceMatcher returns 0.25.